# Apache configuration adds port 80 to a URL with parameters

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ssl, laravel-5

Every time a link with parameters is clicked on (using Laravel 5 and LAMP), Apache automatically adds a port 80 to the end (which the ssl certificate does not like).

i.e. a href to https://www.example.com/companies?page=2 redirects to https://www.example.com:80/companies?page=2

[image: Apache config 1]
[image: Apache config 2]

Comment: does this also happen when you enter the URL directly on the browser and hit enter or only when you click a link?

Comment: Only when a link (without the port 80) is clicked and not when the direct URL is entered in the browser

Comment: Then I think the issue if from URL Generator, since you are trying to generate ssl link try using secure_url(), example `secure_url('foo/bar', $parameters = []);`

Comment: In this case I cannot because the paginate render box is generating the (non-https) url's i.e. <?php echo $companies->appends(['sort' => $sortBy])->render(); ?>

Comment: Any other ideas @Digitlimit ?

Comment: I think the issue is coming from your virtualhost or .htacess config. see this http://superuser.com/questions/596529/configuring-apache2-to-auto-redirect-calls-to-port-80-to-port-443, maybe you can get a clue from it